# Onchange submit of a form with ajax and without the form id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, forms

My page is composed of a table in which each cell is a form.
I want those forms to submit when I change the value of the input (onchange) but I don't want the whole page to refresh when I do it.

For example, I want the user to be able to enter a value in one cell and then TAB to the next cell whithout losing focus when the first form (the first cell they filled) is submitted.

I have read quite a few pages on the web about this, but none fit my needs since I have one more constraint. The forms my table is made of, are generated via Django so they all have the same id.
So I can't use the id to select the form from inside the (java)script.

I have been trying to use this.form or event.form or $(this).form but to no avail.

Here is what those forms look like :

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="progress_form">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="number" id="percent_cell" name="percentdone" min="0" max="100" onchange="progressChange(event)" placeholder={{ d|prog:task.id }}>%&nbsp;
<input type="hidden" id="percent_cell2" name="task" value={{ task.id }}>
<input type="hidden" id="percent_cell3" name="date" value={{ d|date:"d/m/Y" }}>
<input type="hidden" id="percent_cell4" name="update_progress" value=True>
<input type="hidden" id="percent_cell5" name="tab" value="track">
</form>
```

And here is what my script looks like :

```
function progressChange(e) {
        var form = e.form;
        var dataString = form.serialize();
        alert(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(form).attr( 'action' ),
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
                alert("prout");
            },
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why would you have several inputs with the same `id` attribute?

Comment: maybe `$(this).closest('form')` ? http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: use class instead of Id or change the ids.

Comment: Changing the IDs wouldn't be enough. The number of cells can change depending on the users inputs. It isn't possible to create a script for every possible ID since that number is dynamic.

Comment: Having the same id on many objects is not HTML valid !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Same Id's for several fields and pass the this object to the function progressChange()

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="progress_form">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="number" id="percent_cell0" name="percentdone" min="0" max="100" onchange="progressChange(this)" placeholder={{ d|prog:task.id }}>%&nbsp;
<input type="hidden" id="percent_cell1" name="task" value={{ task.id }}>
<input type="hidden" id="percent_cell2" name="date" value={{ d|date:"d/m/Y" }}>
<input type="hidden" id="percent_cell3" name="update_progress" value=True>
<input type="hidden" id="percent_cell4" name="tab" value="track">
</form>
```

Get the current object Parent element i.e. form and serialize it:

```
function progressChange(obj) {
        var $form = $(obj).closest('form'); // OR var form = obj.from;
        var dataString = $form.serialize();
        alert(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(form).attr( 'action' ),
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
                alert("prout");
            },
        });
    }
```

Comment: I have changed the input IDs since everyone was bothred by that fact. It was merely a result of copy and paste. I have tried to pass "this" as you suggested and to get the form by "obj.parent" but I get the following error in the console : 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'

Comment: Why 'element' in the second line ?

Comment: Actually I copy pasted it sorry about that please check updated code

Comment: Happy To help enjoy :)

Comment: I actually removed the IDs of the hidden inputs since they were not useful.

Comment: you are passing event instead of this object that was the actual problem

Comment: Yes you are right. I blame the website that told me 'this' and 'event' were one and the same :)

Comment: Enjoy Keep Posting :)